# find only one word of multiple lists in a string

Tags: python, string, enumerate

```
from itertools import product

ttext = 'hello how are you?'

list1 = ['abra', 'hello', 'cfre']
list2 = ['dacc', 'ex', 'you', 'fboaf']
list3 = ['ihhio', 'oih', 'oihoihoo']

l = [list1, list2, list3]
```

So i have the lists above and i need to know if there's only one word of the lists that is in ttext (only one)

What i want: for example if in ttext i have "hello my name is brian"  it's going to say 'ok there's only one word' but if i have more than one word of the lists in ttext then 'error'...

here it checked if all the words are in ttext, how can i do to check if there's only one word of all the list that is in ttext

```
for words in product(*l):
    print(words, all(word in ttext for word in words))

(('abra', 'dacc', 'ihhio'), False)
(('abra', 'dacc', 'oih'), False)
(('abra', 'dacc', 'oihoihoo'), False)
(('abra', 'ex', 'ihhio'), False)
(('abra', 'ex', 'oih'), False)
(('abra', 'ex', 'oihoihoo'), False)
(('abra', 'you', 'ihhio'), False)
(('abra', 'you', 'oih'), False)
(('abra', 'you', 'oihoihoo'), False)
(('abra', 'fboaf', 'ihhio'), False)
(('abra', 'fboaf', 'oih'), False)
(('abra', 'fboaf', 'oihoihoo'), False)
(('hello', 'dacc', 'ihhio'), False)
(('hello', 'dacc', 'oih'), False)
(('hello', 'dacc', 'oihoihoo'), False)
(('hello', 'ex', 'ihhio'), False)
(('hello', 'ex', 'oih'), False)
(('hello', 'ex', 'oihoihoo'), False)
(('hello', 'you', 'ihhio'), False)
(('hello', 'you', 'oih'), False)
(('hello', 'you', 'oihoihoo'), False)
(('hello', 'fboaf', 'ihhio'), False)
(('hello', 'fboaf', 'oih'), False)
(('hello', 'fboaf', 'oihoihoo'), False)
(('cfre', 'dacc', 'ihhio'), False)
(('cfre', 'dacc', 'oih'), False)
(('cfre', 'dacc', 'oihoihoo'), False)
(('cfre', 'ex', 'ihhio'), False)
(('cfre', 'ex', 'oih'), False)
(('cfre', 'ex', 'oihoihoo'), False)
(('cfre', 'you', 'ihhio'), False)
(('cfre', 'you', 'oih'), False)
(('cfre', 'you', 'oihoihoo'), False)
(('cfre', 'fboaf', 'ihhio'), False)
(('cfre', 'fboaf', 'oih'), False)
(('cfre', 'fboaf', 'oihoihoo'), False)
```

EDIT:
 if only one word of the lists is in ttext: if ttext =  'hello my name is brian' then 'ok there's only one word 'hello' of the lists that is in ttext' 
but if i have 'hello how are you' i have 'hello' and 'you' so 'not ok two word of the lists are in ttext'

Comment: Are you asking if there is at least one list (L) where ttext contains no more than one word from L? Or are you asking if there is exactly one list (L) where ttext contains exactly one word from L? Or are you asking if there is at most one list (L) where ttext contains at most one word from L? There are lots of possible ways you could do it, and it's not clear from your question which one you want.

Comment: @ChadS.exactly one list (L) where ttext contains exactly one word from L i think, i don't speak english very well, i want to check in all the lists if in ttext there's exactly one word i need one result, if in all the lists only one element is in ttext == ok (not one elements per list, for all the lists checked i need to know if exactly one word is in ttext no more)

Comment: @mathieu, some examples would help

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 'hello my name is mathieu' is ok because there's only the word 'hello' in it ( 1 word that is in the list) but  ' hello how are you?' is not ok because there's 2 words "hello" and "you" that are in the lists.

Comment: @mathieu, do you  want one word exactly or 1 or no words?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i'm not sure i understand, one word exactly (not the number 1)

Comment: @mathieu, yes, I mean there has to be one word in common no more and no less exactly one?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think we are finally there:

```
from itertools import product, chain
from string import punctuation

list1 = ['abra', 'hello', 'cfre']
list2 = ['dacc', 'ex', 'you', 'fboaf']
list3 = ['ihhio', 'oih', 'oihoihoo']

l = [list1, list2, list3]

def test(l, tt):
    counts = {word.strip(punctuation):0 for word in tt.split()}
    for word in chain(*product(*l)):
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        if sum(v > 1 for v in counts.values())  > 1:
            return False
    return True
```

Output:

```
In [16]: ttext = 'hello my name is brian'
In [17]: test(l,ttext)
Out[17]: True
In [18]: ttext = 'hello how are you?'
In [19]: test(l,ttext)
Out[19]: False
```

Comment: i got this http://pastebin.com/Y7zfdrMA now how can i know here that there's two words that are in the list (so it's not ok) "hello" and "you" are in ttext so 'not ok'

Comment: @mathieu, I changed the code, what is incorrect in the output?

Comment: ok i get the same result, but i don't see how i can use it, i would like to know with one output if "only one word of the lists is in ttext" then var = True

Comment: yield it in a function

Comment: i'm sorry but this way i still have multiple True and False, i want to know if in ttext there's only one word that is amoung the lists so i can do something. 'if there's only one word in ttext that is in the lists" then a = True else a = False. then after  i use 'if a = true: do somthing'

Comment: Ok so what do you expect?  Are we talking about one word in all the lists?

Comment: there must be a confusion, i except to know if in ttext there's is only one word no more, that is in in any of the lists, if there's several words in ttext that are in any of the lists then > "false"

Comment: @mathieu, I made another edit, if that is not it I am not sure what you want.

Comment: yes this is exactly what i wanted thank you very much for your help !

Comment: how can i do if in my lists i have words with a space in it ?      'i am', 'you are', 'they do'  ...

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you trying to achieve here, but you could try something like this:

```
for words in product(*l):
    print(words, len(word for word in words if word in ttext) == 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for list in l:
    if 'hello' in list:
        print(list, 'this one got hello in it')
```

or maybe instead of using all use any
`print(words, any(word in ttext for word in words))`

Comment: but 'any' will match any word if there's not only 'hello'.. i want to know if there's only one of the words in the lists that is in ttext (not necessarily hello)

Answer (score -1):

Python treats the sum of two boolean values like they are 1's and 0's. This means you can check for one true value in a list by adding all of the values in the list and checking if that is 1. The following function will check if there are x true values in the list of booleans:

```
def xNumberAreTrue(booleans, x):
    return sum(booleans) == x
```

In your case this function can be used as follows:

```
for words in product(*l):
    print(words, xNumberAreTrue([word in ttext for word in words], 1))
```

Where `word in ttext` evaluates to `true` or `false`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!